# R cannot be resolved to a variable (on google maps)

Tags: android, google-maps

i know this sound stupid by asking the question that many people had already asked before, but i am getting frustated by now because every answer that i looked after (more time than i care to mention), regarding those error could not make my code right. 
i watched the code making in youtube and downloaded [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc&list=LL1hP_gxLZo7NFvhsqIfYVlw&index=4).

anyway here is my sample code

```
package com.example.googlemapsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final LatLng LOCATION_PALEMBANG = new LatLng(-2.938201, 104.6892742);
private final LatLng LOCATION_JOHOR = new LatLng(1.5618762, 103.6365218);

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    <-----this line (R cannot be   resolved to a variable)

    map  = ((MapFragment)   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); <-----this line (R cannot be resolved to a variable)

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_PALEMBANG).title("Find me here!"));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); <--- this line (same error)
    return true;
}

public void onClick_City(View v) {
   //   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_PALEMBANG);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_PALEMBANG,     9);
    map.animateCamera(update);
}
public void onClick_Burnaby(View v) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_PALEMBANG, 14);
    map.animateCamera(update);

}
public void onClick_Surrey(View v) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_JOHOR, 16);
    map.animateCamera(update);

}

}
```

and this is my android manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemapsdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>   



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library
    android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCravI-Yxyh1702ZX9s4O5cL_lWmoGz9qo"/>
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and activity main code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnJohor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onClick_Johor"
    android:text="Johor" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurrey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPalembang"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick_Palembang"
    android:text="Palembang" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onClick_City"
    android:text="City" />
```

also i'm having a problem with my values-v14, it is said that :" Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'." 
please can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by either of these possibilities:

- The most probable: You have a syntax error in any of your layout files (i.e., the files located under the *res\layout* folder of your project). The bad thing of this is that Eclipse won't warn you and tell you where's the error, so you'll have to go one by one looking for the syntax (probably an unmatched tag, an unmatched attribute, etc.) and fix the issue.
- The other possibility is a syntax error within your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Same goes here, check it for syntax errors.

One of these two will fix your issue.